# Is there a way to customize the name of a Kubeflow Pipeline visualization?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I created a pipeline with parallel independent operations, each one returning Confusion Matrix, ROC Curve and other metrics.

Each output visualization has a default title, like *confusion-matrix* and *confusion-matrix-2* that does not permit to understand to which brach it comes from.

[image]

Is there a way to customize dynamically this feature as for pipeline steps' names?